# Apache mod_proxy_html Substitute: how to re-use part of regex match? (regex variables?)

Tags: regex, apache, apache2, mod-proxy, apache2.2

*[Full disclosure: Cross-post between here and ServerFault, because I believe the audiences (server admins & devs) are distinct enough to warrant asking the question to both separately.]*

Hi all,

Have a unique URL-rewriting situation in Apache.

I need to be able to take a URL that starts with

```
"\u002f[X]"
```

or

```
'\u002f[X]"
```

Where X is the rest of some URL, and substitute the text

```
"\u002fmeis2\u002f[X]
```

I'm not sure how the Regex works in Apache -- I think it's the same as Perl 5? -- but even then I'm a little unsure how this would be done. My hunch is that it has to do with Regex grouping and then using $1 to pull the variable out, but I'm entirely unfamiliar with this process in Apache.

Hoping someone can help -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Group the text that you want to re-use with parens, and use `$1` in the substitution. Use the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\u002f(.*) /\u002fmeis2\u002f$1
```

(I am not certain that mod_rewrite handles unicode escapes, but it seems so from your question.)

Comment: Thank you for the response! We're actually using mod_proxy_html with a reverse proxy configuration in Apache to try to do it that way. Should the regex work the same for the Substitute command? To clarify, we're re-writing link text within a page, not just re-writing the URL (which I think is what mod_rewrite is limited do, no?) We're using mod_proxy_html with ProxyHTMLEnable and ProxyHTMLExtended both set to "on".

Comment: @goober: Sorry, I didn't notice the mod-proxy tag. I don't now about that module. (But the regex can't differ much.)

Comment: I've just been informed that we're looking only for the next character after the string. Would updating to ^\u002f(.) do the trick in this case?

Comment: Though our problem ended up moving away from this scenario, this is indeed the correct answer to the question. Thanks!